# joomla password encryption

Tags: php, codeigniter, joomla, md5

I need to access the joomla user table `jos_users` for login checking from external php script [codeignitor].

joomla storing password like this

```
4e9e4bcc5752d6f939aedb42408fd3aa:0vURRbyY8Ea0tlvnTFn7xcKpjTFyn0YT
```

Looks like this is not the normal MD5 ,so i cannot use `md5(password)` .

what is the possible way to create the password ?

Thank you.

Comment: deep question :) and if you still think that md5 is the normal way to store passwords you might want to do a little more research on that

Comment: Just a FYI, MD5 should NEVER be used for hashing passwords. Ever. Especially without a salt like in your example.

Comment: Thanks for the info ; But here i am not about to generate a password field.

Comment: Why don't you explain what it is exactly that you are trying to do. Is your purpose to reset or create  a password from an external script? At first that was what it sounded like but now it sounds like you want something different. Are you trying to login?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Joomla passwords are MD5 hashed, but the passwords are salted before being hashed.
They are stored in the database as `{hash}:{salt}` this salt is a random string 32 characters in length.

So to create a new password hash you would do `md5($password.$salt)`

**EDIT**

Okay so for checking a password, say a user `myguy` enters the password `mypassword`, you would retrieve the row from the database that has username `myguy`.

In this row you'll find a password say `4e9e4bcc5752d6f939aedb42408fd3aa:0vURRbyY8Ea0tlvnTFn7xcKpjTFyn0YT`.
You split up the password hash and the salt:

```
$hashparts = preg_split (':' , $dbpassword);
echo $hashparts[0]; //this is the hash  4e9e4bcc5752d6f939aedb42408fd3aa
echo $hashparts[1]; //this is the salt  0vURRbyY8Ea0tlvnTFn7xcKpjTFyn0YT
```

now calculate the hash using this salt and the password `myguy` entered

```
$userhash = md5($userpassword.$hashparts[1]); // This would be 'mypassword' and the salt used in the original hash
```

Now if this `$userhash` and `$hashparts[0]` are identical the user has entered the correct password.

Comment: For an existing password just take the string after the `:` that's the salt. For creating a new password salt just generate a random string. As Er. Anurag Jain's stated in his answer you can easily do this with `JUserHelper::genRandomPassword(32)`

Comment: Sorry ,but still i cant find the answer to the question , assume that user have a pass `hello` ,but how i know that random number ? its generated & stored in db by JOOMLA ..

Comment: @DileepDil See my edit for an explanation how to check the password.

Comment: Did you use real data in this example? I got md5(mypassword0vURRbyY8Ea0tlvnTFn7xcKpjTFyn0YT) == 0ac1a27af8bc4f99edd278dde1fbd18b

Comment: @noisy I did not use real data no. The hash and salt is from the question and I just made up the password, they won't match.

Comment: I think last sentence is wrong, at the end if `$userhash` and `$hashparts` are identical the user entered the correct password.
You could check this directly in database, just in case anybody need it:
`select * from ?_users where concat(md5(concat($your_password,substr(password,34))),substr(password,33)) = password `

Comment: 1426d09a369996aeb0bb35a7af341ff5-->userhash $P$DgfK3C89FAL -->orginalhash is the output its not the same even if the input passqord is correct.

Comment: when i do echo $hash = md5('mypassword0vURRbyY8Ea0tlvnTFn7xcKpjTFyn0YT') . ':0vURRbyY8Ea0tlvnTFn7xcKpjTFyn0YT';

it returns 0ac1a27af8bc4f99edd278dde1fbd18b:0vURRbyY8Ea0tlvnTFn7xcKpjTFyn0YT

Comment: That no longer works. Joomla 3 has a different way to store passwords and it seems nobody knows about it. I need to check the user's entered password with the one saved in the Joomla database table, and I CAN'T do it in PHP.

Comment: Should this really be the accepted answer in 2024...? It's 12 years old, and a top google result.

Answer (score 22):

From joomla Forum, that's what happen behind:

```
A. Generate a password
B. Generate a string with 32 random characters
C. Concatenate Password (Step A) and RandomString (Step B)
D. Take md5(Result of Step C)
E. store Step D Result : Step B Result
```

Example:

```
Generate a password - Let 'testing'
Generate a string of 32 random characters - 'aNs1L5PajsIscupUskaNdPenustelsPe'
Concatenate Password and random string - testingaNs1L5PajsIscupUskaNdPenustelsPe
md5(Step C Result) - 5cf56p85sf15lpyf30c3fd19819p58ly
store step d:step B - 5cf56p85sf15lpyf30c3fd19819p58ly:aNs1L5PajsIscupUskaNdPenustelsPe
```

You can find code in Joomla like

```
$salt = JUserHelper::genRandomPassword(32);
$crypt = JUserHelper::getCryptedPassword("testing", $salt);
$password = $crypt . ':' . $salt;
```

Or We can Say

```
password DB field = md5(password + salt) + ":" + salt
```

Where salt is random 32 char string.

thanks

Comment: I am not about to register a new user ,i need to get the current string on the password field.So that i can match bother user given password and the password on the password field.

Comment: md5 is a one way hash, which means you can only encrypt it but not reverse the decryption, its not possbile to do dycription You can do a thing that first fetch 32 car random string from db password , and with help of that security key create joomla type password from input password and match both...

Comment: how can i fetch the random string from the password ? how its gonna posible ?

Comment: hi joomla db password format is  md5(password + salt) : salt where salt is a secret key so you can explode secret key from given password using  `:` keyword...and then use that with your password to generate joomla type password and then match both password (generated by yoourself and db password) ... thanks

Comment: This same question to, you. Did you use real data in this example? I got md5(testingaNs1L5PajsIscupUskaNdPenustelsPe) == 6e05e46fcc516a612a4afa9b9b7827c7

Comment: No it's example data..not real data..but joomla password encryprion functionality working live given above..

Answer (score 5):

In joomla standard you can create password using the following way

```
                     jimport('joomla.user.helper');
             $salt = JUserHelper::genRandomPassword(32);
             $crypt = JUserHelper::getCryptedPassword($password_choose, $salt);
             $password = $crypt.':'.$salt;
```

you mention that you are accessing from external file(or programs) then if you have joomla installation on other side you can access it from outside the joomla structure.

using joomla default frame work like this

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );//this is when we are in the root
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10409432/access-joomla-session-in-php-codeigniter - this question is still unanswered :)

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't use `preg_split` but `explode` works well.

```
$hashparts = explode (':' , $dbpassword);
```

Comment: Just to note that in some cases, salts can contain any set of characters and that could also include a colon `:` symbol. Using `explode` in this way will create an array with `n+1` number of items where `n` equals number of colons. The `explode` function accepts a third argument which limits how many times to split the string by. Here, we should probably set that to 2. `explode(':', $dbpassword, 2);`

Answer (score 2):

From the joomla source file libraries/joomla/crypt/password/simple.php there are multiple ways they get stored, and some do not have a ':' character.

```
    switch ($type)
    {
        case '$2a$':
        case JCryptPassword::BLOWFISH:
            if (JCrypt::hasStrongPasswordSupport())
            {
                $type = '$2y$';
            }
            else
            {
                $type = '$2a$';
            }

            $salt = $type . str_pad($this->cost, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . '$' . $this->getSalt(22);

            return crypt($password, $salt);

        case JCryptPassword::MD5:
            $salt = $this->getSalt(12);

            $salt = '$1$' . $salt;

            return crypt($password, $salt);

        case JCryptPassword::JOOMLA:
            $salt = $this->getSalt(32);

            return md5($password . $salt) . ':' . $salt;


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Joomla! uses **PhPass**.

```
root/libraries/phpass/PasswordHash.php
```

have a look here. you will see here how the password is generating.

The **$2y** is the default (and preferred) prefix on **bcrypt hashes**.
As for code, you'll want to look inside `JUserHelper's` `hashPassword` and `verifyPassword` methods to see how Joomla's working with things right now.

---

## Some Referances -

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/3.4.1/libraries/joomla/user/helper.php#L296-L387

https://docs.joomla.org/API15:JUserHelper/getCryptedPassword

https://docs.joomla.org/API15:JUserHelper/getSalt

Check the links, I hope you it will helpful :)

Comment: ya looks like from joomla v3.2.2 they have switched to phpass

Answer (score 0):

Joomla "understands" the passwords with "normal" md5.

What I've done in the past (to test a user's login), was to save the original password, encrypt a new one in md5, replace it in the database, test it with the browser (and it works) and when I was done, paste the original password in the database.

Comment: Sorry jackJoe But joomla password is not a normal md5 hash. It is the combination of md5 hash and the joomla secrete key.

Comment: @ShaikhFarooque I know, I was giving a suggestion on how to use normal md5 to test a password.

Comment: Not anymore, It's not using MD5 as of version 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$r = bin2hex(mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));
$p = 'the_password';

$s = $p . $r;
$m = md5($s);

$out = $m . ':' . $r;
echo $out;
```

Len 16 because bin2hex doubles the character size, since 1 byte becomes 2 bytes

Answer (score -2):

If you just use md5($password); it'll work, try it. Joomla has a mechanism and it can work with multiple types of passwords (including, as of late, strong passwords). You don't have to worry about the part after the colon. Just use md5($password) and it'll definitely work.

By the way, this'll also work on Joomla 3.x.