# drupal and joomla hash not salted by default?

Tags: security, hash, joomla, content-management-system, salt

The password recovery mechanism I keep bumping into for joomla, art least, is to add a known, hashed string to the password column of the user table. What that says to me is that the default hashing mechanism is not salted. Am I wrong? Also, I am just curious to know whether or not drupal salts passwords by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal hashes are salted in V7 and later. http://drupal.org/node/493984

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Joomla does salt the passwords before they are md5 hashed.

For a more detailed explanation on the process and how to split them up, please see this:
[joomla password encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428126/joomla-password-encryption)

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Kind of, but the wiki on Joomla says that we should input a known password.  Isn't the purpose of salt to defeat ALL of these ['known-password'][1] databases?


  [1]: http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_recover_your_admin_password?#Change_the_Password_in_the_Database