# What is Joomla 2.5 Password Encryption method?

Tags: php, passwords, joomla2.5

I'm developing a web site using Joomla 2.5. I have Included another sample site for the above parent site. from this child site I'm gonna add new users to the database. but these two sites are uses different method to password encryption.

I found something on web as Joomla encryption but it seems to be not working.

```
function genRandomPassword($length=32) 
{
$salt       = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
$makepass   = '';
mt_srand(10000000*(double)microtime());
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
    $makepass .= $salt[mt_rand(0,61)];
return $makepass;
}

    if ( strlen($_POST['pwd']) > 100 )
    {
        $_POST['pwd'] = substr( $_POST['pwd'], 0, 100 );
    }

    $salt = genRandomPassword();
    $pass= md5(stripslashes($_POST['pwd']).$salt) .':'.$salt;
```

Isn't this the method or where am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428126/joomla-password-encryption

Comment: I think Joomla 2 changed the password related code. The Joomla 1.5 code was horribly broken, and the code you posted is horribly broken too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the way; thinks this will help someone else :)

```
    if ( strlen($_POST['pwd']) > 100 )
     {
        $_POST['pwd'] = substr( $_POST['pwd'], 0, 100 );
     }

     $salt = genRandomPassword();
    //$pass is the encripted password
     $pass= md5(stripslashes($_POST['pwd']).$salt) .':'.$salt;
```

Hash generation as follows:

```
    function genRandomPassword($length = 32)
    {
     $salt = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
     $len = strlen($salt);
     $makepass = '';
     mt_srand(10000000 * (double) microtime());

     for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i ++) {
        $makepass .= $salt[mt_rand(0, $len -1)];
     }

     return $makepass;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I find the answer :
A. user typed password - 'testing'

B. take from database record which you saved for this user: 5cf56p85sf15lpyf30c3fd19819p58ly:aNs1L5PajsIscupUskaNdPenustelsPe

C. concatenate user password with second part of record (from step  -> testingaNs1L5PajsIscupUskaNdPenustelsPe

D. generate MD5 of step C

E. compare result of step C with first part of record from step B (5cf56p85sf15lpyf30c3fd19819p58ly), if its the same it means user typed correct password

Answer (score 1):

I dont think we can get salt in new joomla versions. the pattern dividing password and salt with ":" is no more being used by joomla.

I got to log the user in from external source using joomla username and password. This works for 2.5.24(as I worked on this version when I used it. hope it should work with joomla 3.x.x as well)

I'm doing this login functionality with the following code in the function called

```
onUserAuthenticate($credentials, $options, &$response)
```

this is how I've used for log in user:

```
 // Get a database object
$db   = JFactory::getDbo();
$query   = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select('id, password');
$query->from('#__users');
$query->where('username=' . $db->Quote($credentials['username']). 'OR email=' . $db->Quote($credentials['username'])) ;

$db->setQuery( $query );
$result = $db->loadObject();

//######################



if ($result)
{
   $match = JUserHelper::verifyPassword($credentials['password'], $result->password, $result->id);
      if ($match === true)
   {
      $user = JUser::getInstance($result->id); // Bring this in line with the rest of the system
      // echo 'here'; print_r($user);die('xxxxxssyyyyyyeeeeesssss');
      $response->email = $user->email;
      $response->fullname = $user->name;

      if (JFactory::getApplication()->isAdmin())
      {
         $response->language = $user->getParam('admin_language');
      }
      else
      {
         $response->language = $user->getParam('language');
      }
      $response->status = JAuthentication::STATUS_SUCCESS;
      $response->error_message = '';
   }
}
```

hope this helps some one!!

Comment: Do you know the internal workings of the verifyPassword function, as I need to know how Joomla does this encryption

Comment: Joomla is actually the phpass portable hashing internally you cann see all the implementation from here http://www.phoca.cz/joomla/api/source-class-JUserHelper.html#12-805