# Which piece of php code ecnrypts password during login in Joomla?

Tags: php, encryption, joomla

If I understand correctly, during user login Joomla encrypts entered plaintext-password  to md5 hash with salt and then compares it to the hash already stored in db. I just can't find the part of joomla code which conducts such comparison. 
Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: can't remember quite well, but look inside the Juser object definition

Answer (score 2):

acording to [this link](http://docs.joomla.org/API15%3aJUser/bind) what you're looking for is in `libraries/joomla/user/user.php`

Answer (score 2):

This is the code section

```
             jimport('joomla.user.helper');
             $salt = JUserHelper::genRandomPassword(32);
             $crypt = JUserHelper::getCryptedPassword($password_choose, $salt);
             $password = $crypt.':'.$salt;
```

[almost same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428126/joomla-password-encryption/10428705#10428705)

Comment: Guys, thanks a looot to everybody. You helped me so much! Hope, someday i'll be able to help u))