# Joomla users to another DB

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I want to move my joomla DB users to a new DB I'm using MD5 hash.

I read this question here:
[joomla password encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428126/joomla-password-encryption)

What can I do so that my users can access the new site (new DB) with their passwords?

Is it possible for me to migrate them to the new database as MD5 hash?

Comment: You should never use a simple MD5 hash to store passwords. Older Joomla versions use md5+salt. Since the salt is stored in the database  in your new system you would need to create the Joomla method for matching.  Also ircmaxell https://github.com/ircmaxell has some good classes for managing different styles of passwords including Joomla style.

Comment: thanks, how can i implement same hash as joomla to store passwords?

Comment: Just read the code, you haven't even said what version you are using.  Honestly, I'm not being mean, but working with passwords is extremely serious and dangerous, you need to be able to read and implement the code.  This is not a job for copy and paste from SO. People use the same passwords on lots of sites, you put them all at risk if you do it wrong. There are many other ways you can manage authentication on your application from joomla and vice versa.