# How do you reset the Joomla password?

Tags: joomla

I lost the administrator password, but I got the [cPanel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPanel) and [phpMyAdmin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin) access.

I need to reset the administrator password with a new one.

According to this page, https://docs.joomla.org/Resetting_a_user_password this is possible. But the instructions end with this confusing statement:

> Remember to reset the password again from the back-end, as the MD5
>   encryption is much more secure this way.

How do you *'reset the password again from the back-end'*?
What do they mean here?

The full instructions outlined on that Joomla documentation page is as follows (I'm quoting for completeness of the full picture):

Resetting in PhpMyAdmin

If you have lost your admin password and you can't log into the backend, then you're able to reset the password in your PhpMyAdmin. Complete the following steps:

Select your database in phpMyAdmin

Select the prefixofyourtable_users table.

Click "Browse" and select "Edit" (the small pen icon) on the user whose password you wish to reset.
You will now see all user data in a form. Under the "password" field, you will see a long list of encrypted letters. Delete these letters, and type in a new password.

BEFORE saving, remember to select "MD5" in the "function" dropdown list.

Save your new password and log into the backend of your Joomla site. Remember to reset the password again from the back-end, as the MD5 encryption is much more secure this way.

Comment: have you chcked this - https://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_recover_or_reset_your_admin_password%3F

Answer (score -1):

Once you're able to log into Joomla backend - simply update the admin password there. You can re-use the same one if you want.
To answer the question why it's more secure that way - that's because the password will also be salted before being MD5-hashed.
More info here: [joomla password encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428126/joomla-password-encryption)

Edit: I guess, they meant re-set (set again) rather than reset in the doc.